# Query SQL Server geography data type against a bounding box

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm currently storing geographic locations as data type geography in my SQL Server database and performing radius queries against it without issue.

Is it possible to query against it using a polygon bounding box of points so that the results returned fit within the bounding box?

Comment: here it is - never tried it though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: hmm, that's plane geometry though, so it isn't really it

Comment: you'd use STContains method on the geography Data Type

Comment: @Cato don't be too harsh on yourself, your link is a sibling of the right one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return `GEOGRAPHY` points that are within a `GEOGRAPHY` Polygon thaen what you need is [STIntersects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stintersects-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

The example shown in the link doesn't include a query against Tables but this is possible too.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.table1      T
INNER JOIN
    #dbo.Polygons   P   ON  T.GeogCol.STIntersects(P.PolyGeogCol) = 1
```